# Visual Studio will not release my dll

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Every so often, when I try to rebuild my project, I get the message that the DLL is still in use.  From the windows explorer I cannot delete the dll in question.  I ran Handle to see what was using the dll, and it pointed me back to devenv.exe.

Does anyone know why this happens, any way to prevent it, or some way to release the DLL without closing and re-opening Visual Studio?

If you need more details, please request them.

Comment: Check to see if you have a rogue process named something like "vshostXYZ.exe". There's an intermediary executable it fires up between the app and the debugger.

Comment: Possibly a silly suggestion, but can you use "Clean solution" in VS2010? And if so, does this have any effect? (I'm a VS2012 user sorry!)

Comment: I'll try Clean Solution, although I doubt it will help....As for the vsHost process, it isn't there.  I think it has something to do with the style of project...the debug runs an external executeable that itself references the dll I generate, rather than generating the exe directly, or using a web host, which is I believe what VSHost is there for...